# error: value map is not a member of (sbt.TaskKey[sbt.File], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.TaskStreams])

Tags: scala, sbt

Im trying to install setpropex utility for Android emulator on my ubuntu VM. Build.sbt file has the following code

```
import sbt.IO
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

name := "setpropex"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

exportJars := true

test in assembly := {}

libraryDependencies += "net.java.dev.jna" % "jna" % "4.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"

val dalvikTask = TaskKey[Unit]("dalvik", "build a command line program for Android")

(dalvikTask := (assembly, streams)  map { (asm, s) =>

  val appName = "setpropex"

  val dexFileName = s"$appName.dex"
  s"dx --dex --output=$dexFileName ${asm.getPath}"

  val target = new File(appName)
  IO.copyFile(new File("self-running.sh"), target , true)

  val appData="data.tar"
  s"tar -cf $appData run.sh com $dexFileName"

  IO.append(target, IO.readBytes(new File(appData)))

  s"chmod +x $appName"

  s.log.info(s"Android cmdline app: $appName build successful!")
  s.log.info("Output: " + new File(".").getCanonicalPath + "/" + appName)

  s"adb push $appName /data/local/tmp"
  s"adb shell /data/local/tmp/$appName"

})
```

When I run the command "sbt dalvik", I get the following error

```
error: value map is not a member of (sbt.TaskKey[sbt.File], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.TaskStreams])
dalvikTask := (assembly, streams) map {(asm, s) =>
[error] Type error in expression
```

It seems to me that im missing something quite fundamental in the syntax. Im a complete noob in scala language and im using it only for this particular project. Could someone kindly guide me in rectifying this error? I would be happy to provide any further clarifications, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be about this project:

https://github.com/wuhx/setpropex

It seems like the build system was written with an old sbt version in mind. Try creating a `project/build.properties` file with the content `sbt.version=0.13.18`.

Or you can migrate to the newer sbt 1.0 syntax:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+from+the+tuple+enrichments . However for this to work you'll probably also need to upgrade your sbt plugins as the plugin API changed after sbt 0.13.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It compiled successfully but now im facing another issue. I'll do some work on that and then get back on the forum if needed. Thanks, once again...